# How do you use VSCode Live-Server to detect changes? I can not seem to get the right settings

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code

I am using the latest release 5.6.1 created by Ritwick Dey in VS Code
Powershell is my default shell - Windows 10

I do not know how to use the settings to get the live server to update the changes I place in the HTML/CSS/JS files without using the default setting for the liveServer.settings.host ( default is 12.0.0.1 ) as this is the only version that actually displays changes in my code.

The problem is when it is set to default and I push the GoLive button the only page that will render is the file open in the VSCode editor and if it is not an html page it usually doesn't display anything. If I place a style tag in the  tag it will update changes and render them on the page.

When I set the port to 5000 (this is the port Flask opens up with) in  `"liveServer.settings.port": 5000`, and change the default of `liveServer.settings.host` to `"liveServer.settings.host": "localhost"` ( I also set the root route to in settings to / ) the page will open up on the root route instead of whatever file I have open in the code editor `BUT I have to do a hard reload` for the browser to detect changes.

1) What is the difference between 12.0.0.1 and localhost in the host setting, and is this playing a principle role in the browser not detecting any changes when it is set to localhost?

2) Is it because I changed the port to match the port that flask opens up on when I run the server.py file?

3) Does it have something to do with Python or the compiler used to run the server page?

4) Why does the page detect changes with the `Style` Tag inside the `Head` tag and using the 12.0.0.1 as the host setting? And why does it show the file-path in the URL when it is run this way? How exactly does the Web Page detect changes?

5) Do I need to use the chrome extension and keep the port at default in live server and just change it with the extension to route to the port my server is using?

```
`{
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "python.jediEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": 

"C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
    "editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide": false,


    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.port": 5000,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.root": "/",
    "liveServer.settings.host": "localhost",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,

    "workbench.iconTheme": "file-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Winter is Coming (Dark Blue - No Italics)"
}`
```

This is the JSON setting for the VSCode editor

```
`from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/')         
def main_page():

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__=="__main__":   
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

My basic server page that runs the application

```
`Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
```

this is what the cmd shows when the server runs with no errors

While it does work for the default it is not fluid, and if there is Jinja2 in the template it is displayed all over the page with the HTML.

It should detect any changes I make with the server on and still work when  navigating to different pages. I want to be able to go from page to page, change CSS values or add some jQuery without having to do a hard reload each time for every page I am working on.

Comment: Make sure the following are met when using the Extension, 

Update visual studio code, bottom left click on settings and "check for updates".
Make sure you saved changes.
Make sure you have no other programs running on the same port as vsc.
Make sure you have body or head tag.
Live Reload is not possible without body or head tag.

Ref : https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/236#issuecomment-511129075